# Android N Beta update failed, how can I try again?

Tags: updates, 7.0-nougat, android-beta-program

I enrolled in the beta program.  OTA update appeared, downloaded, unpacked and restarted. Then it loaded up a great little "ERROR" screen with a sick looking Android :/

After restart, it booted back up in Marshmallow.

OK, so no big loss, just time. Happy to try again...but I can't find a way to force the OTA to reappear?

Comment: I assume you're already unsuccessfully tried Settings -> About phone -> System updates -> Check for update?  Also, was your phone rooted and/or modified from stock in any way?

Comment: @Chahk yep, repeatedly, and no, not modified at all. However, I can answer now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it just took time. By the next morning I had another alert asking me to download and install the beta. Despite having checked for updates and restarted the phone to see if I could trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

My first download failed. I unenrolled (on the same page where you enroll)...waited a few minutes, the re-enrolled and got another download message.

The second download/install worked fine.

Apparently this has been true for others as well.